# android studio cannot resolve symbol on functions and ID's

Tags: android-studio

Total noob here. Can't get the MainActivity to recognise any function or IDs. Tried a few of the simpler solutions;
- (File -> Indicate Cashes) --> (Invalidate and Restart)
- Clean project
- Rebuild project

cheers

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJwu.png)
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtpx4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soldier, lowercase that private